# How to add not valid pattern to Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, spring, xss, hibernate-validator

I read [owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_scripting) article about XSS attacks and how to prevent them.

In Example 2 they said:

> If they are filtering for the < or the open of  you should try various methods of encoding:
>
> ```
> <script src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js></script>
>
> %3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js%3e%3c/script%3e
>
> \x3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js\x3e\x3c/script\x3e
> ```

I use Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380) to secure app and `@SafeHtml` annotation to secure every `String` field.

The problem is when I try to test various patterns from owasp examples:

```
User user = new User();
user.setFirstName("aaa<img src=`~`onerror=prompt(666)>a");
user.setMiddleInitial("<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>");
user.setLastName("\"><ScRiPt>alert(document.cookie)</ScRiPt>");
user.setPhone("<scr<script>ipt>alert(document.cookie)</script>");
user.setFax("<script src=\"http://attacker/xss.js\"></script>");
user.setCellular("<script type=\"text/vbscript\">alert(DOCUMENT.COOKIE)</script>");
user.setEmail("<script src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js></script>");
user.setAlertMethodCd("%3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js%3e%3c/script%3e");
user.setHrid("\\x3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js\\x3e\\x3c/script\\x3e");
user.setOrgUserId(">\"><script>alert(\"XSS\")</script>&");
user.setAddress1("\"><STYLE>@import\"javascript:alert('XSS')\";</STYLE>");
user.setAddress2("<IMG SRC=\"javascript:alert('XSS');\">");
user.setCity("<IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>");
user.setZipCode("<IMG SRC=JaVaScRiPt:alert('XSS')>");

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);

Iterator<ConstraintViolation<User>> iterator = violations.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ConstraintViolation<User> cv = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(cv.getRootBeanClass().getName() + "." + cv.getPropertyPath() + " " + cv.getMessage());
}
        assertEquals(14, violations.size());
```

Actual result:

```
User.fax fax should be valid
User.firstName First name should be valid
User.middleInitial middleInitialshould be valid
User.cellular cellular should be valid
User.orgUserId orgUserId should be valid
User.address2 address2 should be valid
User.phone phone should be valid
User.email Email should be valid.
User.city city should be valid
User.zipCode zipCode should be valid
User.lastName lastName should be valid
User.address1 address1 should be valid

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :14
Actual   :12
```

As you see:

```java
user.setAlertMethodCd("%3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js%3e%3c/script%3e");
user.setHrid("\\x3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js\\x3e\\x3c/script\\x3e");
```

can pass `@SafeHtml` annotation.

Do you have any experience with such problems? Can I add somehow new patterns to blacklist?

Answer (score 1):

`@SafeHTML`use very simple encoding for HTML entities, it's why the data pass the validator.

I recommend to use a very strong encoder([OWASP Java Encoder for example](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project)) to fight XSS.

- If you need more patterns to test the bad `@SafeHTML` validator see => https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet .

**Any way the best way to prevent XSS is to use WhiteList validation patterns and use good encoding** => https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md